# Facebook, Twitter, Google login in Fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, twitter, authentication

I was already able to login with all 3 services when using Activity, but when I tried to change to fragments, as soon as I confirm the permission on facebook/twitter or click the google login button, the app close. No errors, just close.

I tried to debug the "onActivityResult" (fragment and activity) and none of them is called.

Am I missing something?

The activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@BindView(R.id.splash_container)
RelativeLayout container;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);



    new SecurePrefManagerInit.Initializer(getApplicationContext())
            .useEncryption(true)
            .initialize();

    FragmentSplash fragmentSplash = new FragmentSplash();
    final FragmentLogin fragmentLogin = new FragmentLogin();

    //boolean dayNight = SecurePrefManager.with(this).get("night_mode").defaultValue(false).go();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean dayNight = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("night_mode", false);
    if(!dayNight){
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    }

    addFragment(fragmentSplash);



}

private void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.add(R.id.splash_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);


    transaction.commit();
}

private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction  transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.splash_container, fragment)
    //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    .disallowAddToBackStack();

    transaction.commit();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.com_facebook_fragment_container);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

}

The fragment:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);


    mContext = getActivity();
    loginFb = new LoginButton(getActivity());
    loginFb.setFragment(this);
    mLoginTwitter = new TwitterLoginButton(getActivity());

    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null ) {
                UtilsLibrary.showToastShort(mContext, "Logou");
                //user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChooseActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                UtilsLibrary.showToastShort(mContext, "Deslogou");
            }
        }
    };

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MyApp.getInstance().getApplicationContext())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    UtilsLibrary.showToastLong(mContext, "Error");
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
        setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));
    }


}

public static FragmentLogin newInstance(){
    FragmentLogin fragmentLogin = new FragmentLogin();
    return fragmentLogin;
}

@OnClick(R.id.login_twitter_btn)
public void loginTwitter(View view){
    signTwitter();
}

@OnClick(R.id.login_google_btn)
public void loginGoogle(View view){
    signInGoogle();
}



@OnClick(R.id.logout_google_btn)
public void logOutAccounts(View view){
    if(user != null){
        mAuth.signOut();

        switch (user.getProviders().get(0)){
            case "google.com":
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(Status status) {
                                // ...
                            }
                        });
                break;
            case "facebook.com":
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                break;

            case "twitter.com":
                Twitter.logOut();
                break;

        }
    }


}

@OnClick(R.id.login_facebook_btn)
public void loginFacebook(View view){


    // startActivity(new Intent(this, ChooseActivity.class));
    signFacebook();

}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

private void signInGoogle(){
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

private void signTwitter(){



    mLoginTwitter.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // The TwitterSession is also available through:
            // Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()
            TwitterSession session = result.data;
            // TODO: Remove toast and use the TwitterSession's userID
            // with your app's user model

            handleTwitterSession(result.data);

            String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
            Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
        }
    });

    mLoginTwitter.callOnClick();



}

private void signFacebook(){


    //LoginButton loginFb = new LoginButton(getActivity());
    loginFb.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginFb.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            // ...
        }
    });
    loginFb.callOnClick();
}

private void handleTwitterSession(TwitterSession session){
    AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
            session.getAuthToken().token,
            session.getAuthToken().secret);

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });

}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + task.getResult().getUser().getDisplayName());
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (FacebookSdk.isInitialized()) {
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    mLoginTwitter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // ...
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());



    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);


    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    //Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + account.getGivenName());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());

                    }
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

}
[image: What is happening]

Comment: Hi Spotik, better approach would be to setup them one by one. For your google login change  getActivity().startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN) in signInGoogle() to startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN). Hopefully this thread helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment.

Comment: @RishabhBhatia same thing =/

Comment: Would it be feasible for you to upload minimal social login code to git, i can help you get started with social logins.

Comment: @RishabhBhatia the social logins are working if I use activities. The problem its just using fragments. And thks again for helping =)

Answer (score 0):

Update the `onActivityResult()` to this with this line
 Fragment fragment =

```
 getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.splash_container);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

try this.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Fragment fragment = 
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.splash_container);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (FacebookSdk.isInitialized()) {
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    mLoginTwitter.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```